# How can i get form1 location when dragging the form around when the form is transparent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to get in real time the form1 location when i drag the form around.
Since the form is transparent i can drag it only on it's borders.

I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form_Location
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            TransparencyKey = Color.LightGreen;
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point p = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First this code is not right i tried when the form is not reansparent it's not giving me the location when dragging the form.

Second problem is when the form is transparent you can't get click events on the form. So the event/s Form1_MouseDown and Form1_MouseMove not working.

I want to get the X and Y of the form1 location while dragging the form around in real time.

Comment: you can use the [`Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx) event that occur when the form is moved, then use Form.Location property to get the position of the form.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this post. It shows how to use opacity to (almost) make the form invisible..